Quill editor adding extra space between content and list items in Angular
Quill editor adding extra space between content and list items in Angular. Where as we don't need this space. Please someone help to resolve
HTML
<quill-editor [(ngModel)]="htmlText" placeholder="Enter Text" [modules]="quillConfig</quill-editor>

TS
htmlText = '<p>Testing List gap between list items and above header</p><ol><li>one</li><li>two</li></ol>';

LINK OF SAMPLE: Sample Link
Final output is like below

